# why won't background colour won't show up :(

Tags: html, css

I'm new to web development and cannot figure out why the background colour will not show up for 2 of my classes(`.work` & `.education`) but does for my header & footer? Apologies if this is very poorly worded! I thought perhaps it was something to do with the margins of the body so I have had a play around but still no luck.

### /* Global styles*/

```
.content-wrap {

    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 5px solid black

}

.column-narrow {

    width: 35%;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 0%;

}
.column-wide {

    width: 62%;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 1%;

}


/* Header & Footer*/
------------------------------------
header, 
footer {

    background: #07BEB8;
    color: white;

}
header h1,
header h2 {
    color: #EDF2F4;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
/* Work Experience*/
------------------------------------
.work {

    background: #BDD9BF;

}

h3 ~ p {

    margin: 0;
}
.job-description {

    margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.job-description p:first-of-type {

    margin-top: 0;
}

/* Education*/
------------------------------------
.education {
    background: aqua;
}

p + h3 {
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

/*html*/
    ------------------------------------

```
<!-- // Work Experience -->
    <section class="work">
        <div class="content-wrap">
            <h2>Work Experience</h2>
            <!-- Job Details: copy this block to add more positions. -->
            <div class="column-narrow">
                <h3>Marketing & Social Media Manager</h3>
                <p class="uppercase">Beauty9</p>
                <p>September 2018 - Present</p>
            </div>
            <div class="column-wide job-description">
              <p>........</p>
            </div>

<!-- // Education -->
                <section class="education">
                    <div class="content-wrap">
                        <h2>Education</h2>

                        <!-- School details: copy this block to add more schools. -->
                        <h3>University Of Bournemouth</h3>
                        <h4>BSc Arhaeology, 2018</h4>
                        <p>4 year course with 1 year in industry</p>
```

Comment: Could you post your html. The code should work

Update: I have tried your code and it works perfectly fine. There's something wrong with your html

Comment: Aren't your DIVs empty? Need to see some HTML to help you there.

Comment: Edit your question and add your HTML. Don't put your code as comments please, it's illegible.

Comment: @Helenesh sorry i have updated it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's the dashes in front of your code. I put it in a snippet below and it works fine.

```css
.content-wrap {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 5px solid black
}

.column-narrow {
  width: 35%;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 0%;
}

.column-wide {
  width: 62%;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 1%;
}


/* Header & Footer*/

------------------------------------ header,
footer {
  background: #07BEB8;
  color: white;
}

header h1,
header h2 {
  color: #EDF2F4;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* Work Experience*/

.work {
  background: #BDD9BF;
}

h3~p {
  margin: 0;
}

.job-description {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.job-description p:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 0;
}


/* Education*/

.education {
  background: aqua;
}

p+h3 {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<section class="work">
  <div class="content-wrap">
    <h2>Work Experience</h2>
    <!-- Job Details: copy this block to add more positions. -->
    <div class="column-narrow">
      <h3>Marketing & Social Media Manager</h3>
      <p class="uppercase">Beauty9</p>
      <p>September 2018 - Present</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column-wide job-description">
      <p>........</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: what dashes do you mean? as in the comments in the code?

Comment: Look at my code - Look at `header`. There's a bunch of dashes in front of it. I removed those from `.work` and it worked fine. If that's not the problem, idk what's the problem for you. It seems to be working just fine in my snippet.

Comment: Thank you so much! It has worked! that was a silly type of mine! those dashes were supposed to be commented in!

Comment: Accept the answer if it has worked for you, Because someone else could have the same issue as you. Show some appreciation for @AniketG who took his time to help you out!

Comment: @neesy No problem. I've done this many times. I spend hours on a simple mistake like a missing semi-colon. And as Kebab Programmer said, accept the answer if it has worked to let others know that it has worked (not everyone reads every comment)